# Select Query getting multiple records pass it to another query

Tags: postgresql

I am getting confused of using multiple select queries want to handle it in single loop.
I am having 2 select queries, In first select query for suppose I am getting 10 records and I have to match these 10 records with another table and will genereate 20 records.

```
select   distinct sk.system_keyword_id   
from system_goal_keyword_match sk  
  inner join user_goal_assoc ug   on ((ug.goal_id = sk.goal_id) and ug.creater_id = 35)

select category_id 
from system_goal_keyword 
where id = *****
```

I want to use loop for these two queries ? can u help me in postgres.

Comment: Use the `IN` operator: `select category_id  from system_goal_keyword where id = (select sk.system_keyword_id  from system_goal_keyword_match sk  ....)`